# Flex unzip/uncompress huge files

Tags: apache-flex

I am having an AIR applicaiton which is supposed to uncompress the file of huge size (>1GB)

I tried commonly discussed utilities i.e. FZip nochump and few more
I face the same problem with all of them, 
They tyr to unzip the entire file in the memory (using ByteArray.defalte method)

This works well with the files of small size howevre they just hang the applicaiton if the size of the file is big (>1GB)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is there not a way you could use file spanning similar to the RAR formats. I think 7-Zip's 7Z supports it also. Depending on how to the decompression library is implemented, file spanning could reduce the memory usage theoretically.

Try looking into using the LZMA SDK a la 7-Zip:
http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Maybe there's Flex bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with sammy, Air it's not the best solution for a task like that, IMHO it's better to include in your distribution a native utility to expand your files (remember that you need an utility for each platform that you want to support) then use the [new Air2 API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process.html) to invoke them. Doing this way the expansion of the archive is done in a separate process without freezing your app.

Maybe you can boundle just one utility if you are sure that every platform has a common runtime (ex. java).